# Ember-paper and class?

Tags: ember.js, ember-paper, ember-intl

I'm working on a project made with Ember.js
I'm using `ember-paper` addon for buttons and also `Ember-intl` addon to translate my application (English and French).

I have a basic HTML button with this code:

```
<button class={{if model.active "active"}} {{action "changeLocale" model.locale}}>{{model.locale}}</button>
```

But when I use ember-paper with this kind of code :

```
{{#paper-button accent=true}}Test{{/paper-button}}
```

I can't find a way to add my if statement and the action.

```
{{if model.active "active"}} {{action "changeLocale" model.locale}}>
```

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7f2850c4a92baa6ff405bb99dd91076b)

1) You can call your `action` using `onClick` option inside `{{#paper-button}}` component.

2) You can use `disabled` and `accent` boolean options to set `true` or `false` based on your condition `model.active`

```
{{#paper-button
  onClick=(action "someAction")
  accent=true
  disabled=(unless model.active true)
  accent=(if model.active true)
}}
  Test
{{/paper-button}}
```